# SegFault in dynamically allocated array of structs, C

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, dynamic-allocation

```
typedef struct {
  double x;
  double y;
  long out_x;
  long out_y;
} coords;

typedef struct {
  char name[FIGURE_LEN + 1];
  int coordcount, size_tracker;
  coords *coordinate;
} fig;

fig figure;
fig * figpoint;
```

this is the functions that are being called from the parser.c source file.

```
void initialize_fig(int n, char * name, double x, double y,
                         fig *fig_point)
{
  printf("inside function\n");
  strncpy(fig_point[n].name, name, FIGURE_LEN + 1);
  fig_point[n].size_tracker = 1;
  fig_point[n].coordinate = malloc(sizeof(coords) * fig_point[n].size_tracker);
  assert(fig_point[n].coordinate != NULL);
  fig_point[n].coordcount = 0;
  fig_point[n].coordinate[fig_point[n].coordcount].x = x;
  fig_point[n].coordinate[fig_point[n].coordcount].y = y;
}

void create_FigArray(fig * fig_point, int fig_size)
{
  fig_point = malloc(sizeof(fig) * fig_size);
  assert(fig_point != NULL);
  fig_point = &figure
}
```

i first call create_FigArray like so...

```
create_FigArray(fig_point, 16);
```

i get no seg fault here...
but then i call...

```
initialize_fig(0, Qe, 10.0000, 10.0000, fig_point);
```

the parameters are actually passed through variables but i just wanted to show that they are proper parameters and give an example of what values are passed.
Anyways it hits

```
strncpy(fig_point[n].name, name, FIGURE_LEN + 1);
```

and stops.. segfault must happen here, but why?!

please help, explain and show how to get around this. thank you.

Comment: Please don't edit the question after you have answers. It makes it very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate memory, then you change the pointer

```
fig_point = malloc(sizeof(fig) * fig_size); // allocate here
assert(fig_point != NULL);
fig_point = &figure;  // now you make fig_point point to something else
```

therefore your `fig_point` pointer no longer points to your dynamically allocated memory. If you then do this

```
fig_point[n]
```

you are accessing memory out or range since `figure` is not an array. In addition you pass the pointer `fig_point` to `create_FigArray` directly. This will create a copy of the pointer and hence any changes you make to that argument are in fact only changes to the `copy`. This means that the dynamic memory you that the address stored in `fig_array` after `create_FigArray` has returned is the same as it was before - it is only the `copy` that was changed by the function. If you want to change the pointer you need to use a double pointer argument to the function and then something like

```
void create_FigArray(fig** fig_point, int fig_size)
{
    *fig_point = malloc(sizeof(fig) * fig_size);
}
```

Comment: @user1787262 No dont edit the question!! This makes it very confusing to anyone else trying to answer your question.

Comment: so say i changed it so that the funcs took in fig ** fig_point. would i need to change all the '.' operators to '->'

Answer (score 1):

I dont know but:

First you allocate memory to fig_point:

```
fig_point = malloc(sizeof(fig) * fig_size);
```

And after that you assign the address of figure to it, you should not do that.

```
fig_point = &figure;
```

You could do this instead:

```
figure = *fig_point;
```

Comment: You cant assign the address of figure to your allocated fig_point.

Comment: @askmish this is why i dereference fig_point ... http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Answer (score 1):

- In `create_FigArray` you do this: fig_point = malloc(sizeof(fig) * fig_size); and then this:
  `fig_point = &figure; //figure is a global variable and this causes a memory leak`
- Instead write this:

> ```
> void create_FigArray(fig * fig_point, int fig_size)
> {
>   fig_point = malloc(sizeof(fig) * fig_size);
>   assert(fig_point != NULL);
>   fig_point = &figure;//Remove this line
> }
> ```

- In the function from where you are calling `initialize_fig()` or somewhere, ensure to free the allocated memory.
- Make all the pointers NULL before use and add NULL argument checks in functions dealing with pointers and check NULL pointers before use.